# Android Ubuntu One client on a Motorola Atrix - pictures not picked up from SD card, only from internal card

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

My Atrix runnig the Ubuntu One client does not pickup pictures from the SD card. If I point the camera client back to the default internal SD location it appears to work fine. The does work with the Dropbox and the google+ apps. I know that the way that the SD card are 'mapped' is different on the atrix.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

We'll have improved support of detecting new media from any location soon. Also, can you check with any file explorer (like AndExplorer) what is the mount point of the storage you're trying to pick up from? It can be something like /mnt/sdcard_ext, /mnt/ext_sd, etc.